# Make search engines show related businesses(by name and otherwise), in the search results

Tags: seo, google, local-seo, json-ld

So, I manage the website of a restaurant, "ABC". They have recently opened another outlet in a different area. They called it, "ABC Express".

Both restaurants have their own Google My Business pages. And they both show up in the top 10-15 results in a search for their names.

So far so good.

I'd like to understand if there's anything I can do, in terms of SEO, so that when the user searches for "ABC" the results show "ABC Express" along with "ABC" and vice versa.

What's happening now is, through word of mouth, people are hearing that ABC opened another outlet in this other area. They don't know that the other outlet is called, "ABC Express". So, they google for - "ABC" and the new outlet doesn't even show up in the top 100 results, because it's called "ABC Express".

What I've done to make Google understand the two restaurants are related:

1. Split up their single-page website, into two location pages. One has information about the original - "ABC", the second page has information about the "ABC Express". The landing page just has information about the dishes (common) they serve. Each of these pages shows up independent within the top 10-15 results, which you search for either "ABC" or "ABC Express".
2. The landing page's `JSON-ld` declares, "ABC" as an `Organization` and includes information that's common to both. Each of the location pages includes `JSON-ld` that declares the `@type` as `Restaurant` and then references the parent through `parentOrganization`.

It's been about three weeks since these changes were published and google has indexed all pages (verified in Google Search Console). However, I'm still not seeing the desired results.

Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! ***Is there anything else I could do?*** Wait. Google is very slow. If I think of something else, I will jump in. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Google has already indexed both location pages and they're showing up in top 10-15 results. I'd like to understand if there's any way to tell Google, those two restaurants are related. So, if people search for one, the other also shows up in the search results.